# How can this tiny piece of code be simplified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Like how can I remove the ORs and use another simpler way of doing the same?

```
list = [1, "loki", 2.4]
y = isinstance(list[0] or [1] or [2] or [3], int)
print(y)
```

Comment: ``any(isinstance(x, int) for x in list_)`` ? Donot label variables with in-builts.

Answer (score 0):

**hope it helps**

```
list = [1, "loki", 2.4]
for i in list:
    y = isinstance(i, int)
print(y)
```

Comment: You can introduce a ``break``, if ``int`` is found to avoid further iterations.

Comment: smh this fixed it